# Prevent `useEffect` from looping

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a simple useEffect that I'm not sure how to stop from invoking endlessly. It keeps firing the first `if` conditional endlessly. I've been reading a lot about hooks and I assume (maybe erroneously) that each render of the component results in a **new** invocation of my `useAuth()` and `useUser()` hooks. Since they have new references in memory it's triggering the `useEffect`'s deps since technically it's a new function that exists in the scope of this new component render?

Thats my thought at least, no clue how to fix that if that's indeed that case.

```
const RootPage = ({ Component, pageProps }): JSX.Element => {
  const { logoutUser } = useAuth();  // imported
  const { fetchUser } = useUser();   // imported
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // authStatus();
    const unsubscribe = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(1);
        return fetchUser(user.uid); // async function that fetches from db and updates redux
      }
      console.log(2);
      return logoutUser(); // clears userData in redux
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [fetchUser, logoutUser]);

  ...
}
```

**fetchUser**

```
  const fetchUser = async (uid) => {
    try {
      // find user doc with matching id
      const response = await firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
      const user = response.data();
      // update redux with user
      if (response) {
        return dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USER,
          payload: user,
        });
      }
      console.log('no user found');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

**logoutUser**

```
  const logoutUser = async () => {
    try {
      // logout from firebase
      await firebaseAuth.signOut();
      // reset user state in redux
      resetUser();
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

when I refresh the page with this useEffect on this is output to the console:

[image]

Comment: Inside your custom hooks, you need to wrap the `logoutUser` and `fetchUser` functions in `useCallback`. Have a look at the `useCallback` docs for an explanation.

Comment: If the effect keeps triggering, either it's because its dependencies are changing, OR you could be mounting a new `<RootPage />` component... hard to say without seeing a bit more code.

Comment: Actually, I think maybe I wrapped one of the wrong functions with the useCall back whoops

Answer (score 2):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function onAuthStateChange() {
      return firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          fetchUser(user.uid);
        } else {
          resetUser();
        }
      });
    }
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange();
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [fetchUser, resetUser]);
```

Keeping everything the same && wrapping `fetchUser` and `resetUser` with a `useCallback`, this solution seems to be working correctly. I'm not entirely sure why at the moment.

Comment: Usecallback prevents a function from being redefined unless one of the dependencies in the dependency array changes. Therefore, your wrapped functions do not get redefined on every render, preventing the useEffect from triggering on every render. You're basically memoizing the function.

Comment: That makes sense, I thought `useCallback` had to be called inside the body of a component but evidently it can be called inside a custom hook as well.

Comment: That's right, although technically it _can_ only be called inside the body of a component, because a hook is only called inside the body of a component. It's the same thing.